# perl reporting pipeline delimited

Tags: perl

I am doing a pipeline delimited report using perl.  How do i include the delimiting character | between the fields. | symbol in perl stands for aligning the field to centre.

```
format details =
@<<<<<<<<<<<<  @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  @<<<<<<<<<<<<
"$rtype", "$rdescr", "$rid"

OUTFILE->format_name("details");
write OUTFILE;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using that format, then you could as simply use:

```
print OUTFILE "$rtype|$rdescr|$rid\n";
```

You should think about migrating to lexical file handles  <s>though ISTR that formats require the non-lexical handles</s>.  However, that doesn't automatically truncate the fields to length, which may matter to you.

This code works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open OUTFILE, ">", "file.out" or die "A horrible death";

my $rtype = "ABCDEFG HIJKLMN OPQRST";
my $rdescr = "Abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stuv wxyz?";
my $rid   = "0123456789";

format details =
@<<<<<<<<<<<< | @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< | @<<<<<<<<<<<< |
"$rtype", "$rdescr", "$rid"
.

OUTFILE->format_name("details");
write OUTFILE;


$rtype = "ABCDEFG";
$rdescr = "Abc def";
$rid   = "01234";
write OUTFILE;
```

The output it produces (in `file.out`) is:

```
ABCDEFG HIJKL | Abc def ghi jkl mno pqr  | 0123456789    |
ABCDEFG       | Abc def                  | 01234         |
```

(PS: I tried `\|` first; it produced `\|` in the output, so it was an easy and reasonable inference that the backslash was not actually needed.)

With lexical file handle:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $out, ">", "file.out" or die "A horrible death";

my $rtype = "ABCDEFG HIJKLMN OPQRST";
my $rdescr = "Abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stuv wxyz?";
my $rid   = "0123456789";

format details =
@<<<<<<<<<<<< | @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< | @<<<<<<<<<<<< |
"$rtype", "$rdescr", "$rid"
.

$out->format_name("details");
write $out;


$rtype = "ABCDEFG";
$rdescr = "Abc def";
$rid   = "01234";
write $out;
```

This gives the same output.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Apologies for the delayed response